# Print object attributes in a table in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

I know there are some tools like `hirb` which let you print the contents of a database table in a table format in the console.

But this does not work with object attributes, i.e. those defined in the model, not in the database. Is there some similar tool that lets print these attributes, in proper layout format in the rails console similar to hirb?

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev! If you put that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For added flexibility, you can use something like [terminal-table](https://github.com/tj/terminal-table). With it, you can display *anything* in a table.

```
table = Terminal::Table.new do |t|
  t << ['One', 1]
  t << :separator
  t.add_row ['Two', 2]
  t.add_separator
  t.add_row ['Three', 3]
end

puts table

# +-------+---+
# | One   | 1 |
# +-------+---+
# | Two   | 2 |
# +-------+---+
# | Three | 3 |
# +-------+---+
```